# What is correct syntax with depend parameter flag in Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am using Windows PoweShell to submit jobs to a high performance cluster, and I'm having a problem with the depend parameter flag.  I cannot post the actual code as it would probably get me in trouble at work so here's the gist:

```
job add $jobid /scheduler:xxxxx /name:task1 /workdir:M:\dir foo.exe "foo" -logfile task1.log
job add $jobid /scheduler:xxxxx /name:task2 /workdir:M:\dir foo.exe "foo" -logfile task2.log

job add $jobid /scheduler:xxxxx /name:task3 \depend:task1,task2 /workdir:M:\dir foo.exe "foo" -logfile task1.log
```

The problem occurs when it hits `task2` in `\depend:task1,task2`.  If I skip task2 and remove it from the depend statement, then everything is fine.  Maybe I need some sort of brackets or whatnot to indicate that I'm giving a list, rather than a single parameter, to the depend flag.

What's the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb here, but `task1,task2` is most likely interpreted as a PowerShell array and `/depend` probably doesn't accept that as input (or just the first array element). Try putting the list in double quotes:

```
job add $jobid /scheduler:xxxxx /name:task3 /depend:"task1,task2" ...
```

or using the magic parameter (if you're using PowerShell v3 or newer):

```
job add $jobid --% /scheduler:xxxxx /name:task3 /depend:task1,task2 ...
```